# How's the Copy & Swap idiom really supposed to work, seriously! My code fails

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been hearing about this, very advertised way of implementing an `assign operator=()` in **C++**.

EDIT: MVP(s),

- https://onlinegdb.com/meN5a_I2I (Version 1)
- https://onlinegdb.com/HybpyOO6P (Version 2)

**Version 2:**

```
a.out: main.cpp:52: int main(): Assertion `ptr == a.data()' failed.                                                        
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here's where it seems to fail,

A `copy operator=()` without **Copy & Swap Idiom**:

```
Data& operator=(const Data& rhs)
{
    if(this != &data)
    {
        _size = rhs.size();
        delete[] local_data;
        local_data = new char[_size];
        std::copy(rhs.data(), rhs.data() + rhs.size(), local_data);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

1. Main.cpp with above (non-swap idiom) implementation called,

   ```
   int main(){
      Data a("Some data");
      auto ptr = a.data(); // Obtains a pointer to the original location
      a = Data("New data"); // When a is modified, this modification should effect the 'ptr'
      assert(ptr == a.data()); // Succeeds
      return 0;
    }
   ```

---

Same as above, except with Copy & Swap Idiom:

```
void swap(Data& rhs) noexcept
{
    std::swap(_size, rhs.size());
    std::swap(local_data, rhs.data());
}

Data& operator=(const Data& rhs)
{
    Data tmp(data);
    swap(data);
    return *this;
}
```

**2: With swap idiom implementation:**

```
int main(){
    Data a("Some data");
    auto ptr = a.data(); // Obtains a pointer to the original location
    a = Data("New data"); // When a is modified, this modification should effect the 'ptr' 
    assert(ptr == a.data()); // Fail
    return 0;
}
```

I observe, that there's clean up. But, is the clean and easy implementation of Copy & Swap Idiom supposed to fail here. And, I know that some runtime overhead does occur. But, generally, the Copy & Swap idiom seems a lot cleaner and better.

**EDIT:** I am aware of the self-assignment problem, and that this is supposed to help with that. Self-assignment is exceedingly rare in most programs, so an explicit check adds a small cost to every self-assignment even though the check is almost always false.

Sutter & Alexandrescu shows an assignment operator written in terms of a swap member. This is safe against self-assignment, exception-safe, and re-uses the copy constructor.

**Full code for version 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Data 
{
private:
    char* local_data;
    int _size = 0;
    
    inline int length(const char* str)
    {
        int n = 0;
        while(str[++n] != '\0');
        return n;
    }
    
public:
    Data() {
        local_data = new char[_size];
    }
    
    Data(const char* cdata) : _size { length(cdata) }{
        local_data = new char[_size];
        std::copy(cdata, cdata + _size, local_data);
    }
    
    int size() const { return _size; }
    const char* data() const { return local_data; }
    
    void swap(Data& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(_size, rhs._size);
        std::swap(local_data, rhs.local_data);
    }
    
    Data& operator=(const Data& data)
    {
        Data tmp(data);
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Data a("Some data");
    auto ptr = a.data(); // Obtains a pointer to the original location
    a = Data("New data"); // When a is modified, this modification should effect the 'ptr' (char*)
    assert(ptr == a.data()); // Fails
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even the first version could "fail" at any time. You're just "lucky" that `new[]` happens to return the exact same pointer after `delete[]`. Please take some time to really think about what you compare in the assertion.

Comment: You are right, very true. Good observation. So, honestly, what is a proper and safe, yet efficient way of implementing this, and being able to use it in a context as this one here.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to touch `rhs` in `operator=`?

Comment: I believe you are working under the wrong assumptions. Why would the pointers be equal after the assignment?

Comment: @mrks, I understand your question. But, the Copy & Swap Idiom, and approach, seems to make another *'safe'* copy of the *rhs*, and then work with it.

Comment: @mrks, I tested all of this code. The first version works. But, surely, it too can fail. However, I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, interesting question **re: asserion comparison** here. As far as I know, `auto ptr` obtains a pointer to that original location in memory where data sits. When `a` is modified, this affects `ptr`. Now, with the second example using `swap` the `ptr` loses its content, and thus assertion failure. But, I will inspect in the code to see if there are other things happening i.e. change in address memory location.

Comment: "When a is modified, this affects ptr" is wrong. The variable `ptr` is totally separate and distinct from `a.local_data`. When `a.local_data` is modified the value of `ptr` remains unmodified.

Comment: Let's make another example: `int a = 10; int b = a; a = 20;` Would you expect the value of `b` to change when you modify `a`? That's the assumption your code have right now.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles, see my latest EDIT! Thx.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, that depends on the copy constructor and assignment operator, shallow vs. deep object copy.

Comment: A [mre] should be in the question itself not via external links

Comment: I don't know how to post that, and make code run here in SO! Sorry for that.

Comment: The code doesn't have to be runnable inside stack overflow (that's not current possible with c++ code) and you can include external links to provide runnable versions of you wish but a compilable example should be in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you seem to misunderstand how modifications to `a.local_data` are propagated (or not, as is what happens) to `ptr`.

Lets draw this up, statement by statement:

1. First we have

   ```
   Data a("Some data");
   ```

   Which gives us something like

   ```
   +--------------+     +-------------+
   | a.local_data | --> | "Some data" |
   +--------------+     +-------------+
   ```
2. Then we "copy" the pointer into the variable `ptr`:

   ```
   auto ptr = a.data();
   ```

   Which gives us something like

   ```
   +--------------+
   | a.local_data | --\
   +--------------+    \     +-------------+
                        >--> | "Some data" |
   +-----+             /     +-------------+
   | ptr | -----------/
   +-----+
   ```
3. With the next statement two things happen:

   1. First a new temporary object is created with `Data("New data")`:

      ```
      +--------------+
      | a.local_data | --\
      +--------------+    \     +-------------+
                           >--> | "Some data" |
      +-----+             /     +-------------+
      | ptr | -----------/
      +-----+

      +------------------+     +------------+
      | temporary_object | --> | "New data" |
      +------------------+     +------------+
      ```
   2. Then in the first version where you `delete[]` and `new[]` in the copy-assignment operator this happens:

      ```
      +--------------+     +------------+
      | a.local_data | --> | "New data" |
      +--------------+     +------------+

      +-----+
      | ptr | --> ???
      +-----+

      +------------------+     +------------+
      | temporary_object | --> | "New data" |
      +------------------+     +------------+
      ```

      The temporary object is then destructed, leaving you with:

      ```
      +--------------+     +------------+
      | a.local_data | --> | "New data" |
      +--------------+     +------------+

      +-----+
      | ptr | --> ???
      +-----+
      ```

      Here the value of pointer `ptr` is no longer valid!
   3. In the copy-and-swap version something else happens:

      ```
      +--------------+     +------------+
      | a.local_data | --> | "New data" |
      +--------------+     +------------+

      +-----+
      | ptr | ---------------\
      +-----+                 \     +-------------+
                               >--> | "Some data" |
      +------------------+    /     +-------------+
      | temporary_object | --/
      +------------------+
      ```

      Then the temporary object is destructed leaving you *again* with:

      ```
      +--------------+     +------------+
      | a.local_data | --> | "New data" |
      +--------------+     +------------+

      +-----+
      | ptr | --> ???
      +-----+
      ```

      As before the value of `ptr` is no longer valid.

However the important thing is the disconnect between `ptr` and `a.local_data`. You can modify one, but the other will *not* be modified. Which of course leads to the assert to fail.

That in your example it works for the first case is a *coincidence*, as the memory allocator seems to be reusing the memory passed to `delete[]`. This is of course nothing that can be guaranteed to happen always or even repatedly. As a possible way to break the first "working" example, try creating a new object with a *longer* string, as in

```
a = Data("Much longer string");
```

Comment: As I wrote, they point to the same memory location and content. When the first code runs, it doesn't fail as the way you are describing it. I looked in the debugger, both ptr and a point to the same memory location and get the same content once the line `a = Data("New data");` is called.

Comment: So, a better approach, means it would be: to have a `const char* old= local_data;` and then if the = new[] fails, return the original copy,

Comment: @AlbinM Allow me to repeat myself: That it doesn't fail and both seems to point to the same memory is a ***pure coincidence***. You simply can't rely on that. And in the first case, you're using the "normal" overload of `new[]` which will throw an exception if it fails. So no need to store a copy of the pointer in case it fails.

Comment: Strange answer. OK! So, what is a proper and safe way of doing this?

Comment: @AlbinM It depends on what you mean by "safe" and "proper". And what the use-case is. And why you need to store the independent variable `ptr`. Both variants are "safe" and "proper" as far as I can see, ***if*** you don't keep unrelated pointers to the internal data. It's that pointer `ptr` and its possible use that could lead to problems.

Comment: I don't have any standards for safety or proper. To be honest. I wanted to know more about the promoted and advertised, Copy & Swap Idiom. We share some observations and understanding regarding the memory pointers. But, you mention ***"pure coincidence"***, then it sounds very unsafe.

Comment: @AlbinM One reasons for copy and swap is that it simplifies your code. Simpler code makes it more maintainable and easier to understand.

Comment: Exactly. And I am aiming at writing simpler code, but, it doesn't work for this context. What would be the way to go, to get the "Copy & Swap Idiom" to work in this example? And passing the `assert(...)` not making changes to the code in the `main()` function.

Comment: @AlbinM You can't. I think you need to post a new question about the actual underlying problem you need to solve. And include the detail that you need the external pointer variable `ptr` to remain valid.

Comment: I will post now. Thx a lot dude.

Comment: @AlbinM By the way, an even simpler variant would be to follow [*the rule of zero*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero), by using `std::vector` or `std::string` or other suitable standard container instead of managing memory manually yourself.

Comment: I know, but, I want to remain independent from the containers. And make my own class. Data.