# What would a proper way to go, to get the "Copy & Swap Idiom" to work here?

Tags: c++, c++11

**MY Previous question:**

- [How's the Copy & Swap idiom really supposed to work, seriously! My code fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489236/hows-the-copy-swap-idiom-really-supposed-to-work-seriously-my-code-fails)

---

In the code below, I need the variable `auto ptr` to `remain valid` and the `assertion` to pass.

```
   auto ptr = a.data();
```

Looks like this:

```
   +--------------+
   | a.local_data | --\
   +--------------+    \     +-------------+
                        >--> | "Some data" |
   +-----+             /     +-------------+
   | ptr | -----------/
   +-----+
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Data 
{
private:
    char* local_data;
    int _size = 0;
    
    inline int length(const char* str)
    {
        int n = 0;
        while(str[++n] != '\0');
        return n;
    }
    
public:
    Data() {
        local_data = new char[_size];
    }
    
    Data(const char* cdata) : _size { length(cdata) }{
        local_data = new char[_size];
        std::copy(cdata, cdata + _size, local_data);
    }
    
    int size() const { return _size; }
    const char* data() const { return local_data; }
    
    void swap(Data& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(_size, rhs._size);
        std::swap(local_data, rhs.local_data);
    }
    
    Data& operator=(const Data& data)
    {
        Data tmp(data);
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Data a("Some data");
    auto ptr = a.data(); // Obtains a pointer to the original location
    a = Data("New data");
    assert(ptr == a.data()); // Fails
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: To GIVE some perspective, the following runs perfectly well with the Standard C++ String class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::string str("Hello");
    auto ptr = str.data();
    str = std::string("Bye!");
    assert(ptr == str.data());

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And, I am trying to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: The pointer remains valid, since your class does not have a proper destructor and `"Some data"` is never cleaned up. You example is confusing in several ways though. Why is `operator=` performing a swap? Additionally `ptr` is just a copy of `a.local_data`. Changing one does not have any impact on the other. They are separate pointers that point to the same data.

Comment: But, it does change in this case. I checked in Visual Studio IDE step-by-step, observing the contents and their memory addresses. See a running example here: https://onlinegdb.com/HybpyOO6P

Comment: `ptr` remains valid. `a.local_data` changes. They no longer point to the same data. Your example also crashes since you are performing a swap with a temporary object, so `a` is no longer valid.

Comment: See here, it works: https://onlinegdb.com/meN5a_I2I, but, I am not using the Copy and Swap Idiom. I want to make the code clean, readable, and efficient.

Comment: I already told you 3 ways that your code is wrong in. Just because something compiles and runs, doesn't mean it works.

Comment: So, what is correct then? Don't bring me STL, or already built-in STD stuff. Nor do I want to use shared_ptr<>, unique_ptr<> etc.

Comment: My interest is if this can be achieved with Copy & Swap, if it cannot. Then simply confirm and let me know. Did you see my previous question, I added a link to it at the top of this question.

Comment: @AlbinM Well, your question does not make any sense as you use **false assumption** and then wounder why the code does not give the result you want. Clearly, `std::string` don't use **copy and swap** in that case and **obviously**, if you use copy and swap, then `assert(ptr == a.data());` will fail!

Comment: @AlbinM  Also, there is no guarantees that the assertion won't fails with standard string class. It will most likely fail if the new text is long (say 100 characters). It is an implementation defined behavior in which circumpstance the assertion would pass or fail.

Comment: By the way, your `length` function would fails with an empty string.

Comment: > **your length function would fails**, true. I noticed that too.

Comment: The only reason that your example works with the std::string is because there's a "small string optimization" in the string class implementation.  Basically, there's a _small_ array as a member of the string, which is used unless the string gets bigger than size X (decided by compiler) and THEN it switches to dynamic allocations.  For example, your example would fail if you use strings that are, say, 30 bytes long because then they are on the heap.

Comment: But in general your goal is not reasonable.  If you have a Data object that has a small allocation, and assign to it another one that has a large allocation, you _must_ reallocate the buffer (or move the ptr from the source), and either way that will change the address of the buffer.  You COULD accomplish it if you settled for a fixed size internal buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of correctness, contrary to what some comments indicate, your assignment operator looks correct for copy/swap:

```
Data& operator=(const Data& data)
{
    // Locally this code is fine
    Data tmp(data);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

It makes a copy of the data into tmp, swaps with it.  Thus, the current object's new state is a copy of the data, and the object's old state is inside tmp and should be cleaned up in its destructor.  This is exception safe.

**However**, it depends on *two* key things that you failed to do (as the comments did point out in part):

1. a non-throwing destructor that cleans up the old state.  You omitted this, and it is crucial for proper management of the resources this object owns.

   ~Data()
   {
   delete [] local_data;
   }

*note: you don't need to set it to nullptr, and don't need to check for nullptr, because deleting a null pointer is a noop, and once the destructor begins running, the object ceases to exist (lifetime is over) and so it should never be read again or your program has undefined behavior.*

2. You did not write a copy constructor.

When you don't write a proper copy constructor, the compiler generates one for you that does an element-wise copy.  That means you end up with a copy *of the pointer*, not a copy of the data to which it points!  That is an aliasing bug because both objects will point to (and logically "own") the same memory.  Whichever is destroyed first will delete the memory and corrupt the memory to which the other still points.  Fortunately, a copy constructor is easy to make for your class:

```
Data(const Data& other) : 
    local_data{new char[other._size]}
    _size{other._size},        
{
    std::copy(other.local_data, other.local_data + _size, local_data);
}
```

Things to observe about this copy constructor:

1. if new[] throws, nothing is leaked.  copy() cannot throw.  This is exception safe.
2. the order of initialization is *not* the order listed in the constructor, but the order the data members are declared in the class.  Thus, local_data will be initialized before _size, and so it's important to use other._size for the `new` expression.

The copy/swap idiom is clean, and concise, and can lead to exception safe code.  However, it does have some overhead, as it makes an extra object off to the side, and does the work to swap with it.  The benefit of this idiom is when *multiple operations can throw exceptions*, and you want an "all or nothing" assignment.  In your particular class, the only thing that can throw is the allocation of `local_data` in operator=, and so it is not really necessary to use this idiom in this class.

I think your code should be ok after adding these functions.  In this case, you would benefit from a *move constructor* too, and *move assignment* too, since copying from an rvalue can be optimized, since we know the temporary is about to be destroyed when the assignment completes, we can "steal" its allocation and not have to create one of our own.  This is fast, and also exception safe:

```
Data(Data&& other) : 
    local_data{other._local_data}
    _size{other._size},        
{
    // important!  This prevents other's destructor from
    // deleting the allocation we just pilfered from it.
    // Note, other's size and pointer are inconsistent, but it's
    // about to be destroyed, so it doesn't matter.  If it did,
    // then swap both members, but that's needless more work
    // in this case. 
    other._local_data = nullptr;
}

Data& operator=(Data&& other) {
    _size = other._size;
    swap(local_data, other.local_data);
    return *this; 
}
```

[updated to address this]
As for your main() function, the assertion does not look reasonable.

```
int main()
{
    Data a("Some data");
    auto ptr = a.data(); // Obtains a pointer to the original location
    a = Data("New data");
    assert(ptr == a.data()); // ????
    return 0;
}
```

After you assign to a, the pointer *should* be different, and you should be asserting that the pointers are NOT the same.  But in this case, ptr will be pointing to the *old* address that *a* held, which has been deleted by the time you get to the assertion.  Storing pointers to object internals while modifying those objects is one of the basic recipes for errors.

One last thing: if you write an operator=, or a custom constructor, you almost always need a custom destructor.  Always think of these three together as a special relationship.  This was called the "Rule of Three": if you write any of them, you almost certainly must write all of them.  The rule was expanded to the "Rule of Five" (after c++11) to include *move* constructors and *move* assignment.  You should read up on these rules, and always think of these special member functions together.  Another one to consider (not for this class, but in class design in general) is the best one, the Rule of Zero.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. Lots of thanks. So, if I have understood your from your answer, `Data& operator=(const Data& data)` <-- move in that copy operator is useless, right?

Comment: What would you be moving?  I think the answer is no, you can't move in the traditional copy constructor, because the source object is an lvalue (and it's const, which also indicates it's off limits).  Moving from it would be like ripping its heart out while it's still alive, as in Temple Of Doom.

Comment: But, move and copy behave the same. And I wasn't referring to the traditional "copy constructor", but rather the "copy assignment operator" and the current function.

Comment: Hahaha, it was mostly my own confusion, when I set my mind to try to optimize and improve the code. ..... Hahahahaha, thank you dude!